# ASP.NET - preserve style of HTML element after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewstate

I had long break from ASP.NET development.

I have a div, that is toggled by javascript function, on another element's `onclick` function.

```
 <div id="InsDetail" style="display: none">
```

After postback, the div's state is reverted back to collapsed. What is the easiest way to preserve style of this div between postbacks? (Viewstate maybe?)

Comment: You should inspect the JS function rather to fix this.

Comment: try jquery ajax instead of whole page postback.
ScriptManager and ajaxpanel are asp.net component

Comment: Have you considered using UpdatePanels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hidden field (control) and update the state (e.g 1 = visible 0 = hidden) when change the visibility of the div. Next restore the state in load page event.

more o less

aspx file:

```
  <input runat="server" type="hidden" class="stateDiv" id='stateDiv' />
```

js file or in page:

```
$(function(){
 var visibility = $(".stateDiv").val();
 if(visibility== 1)
   $("#InsDetail").show()
 else
   $("#InsDetail").hide();

 $(your_botton).click(function(){
 //toggle div
  if ($("#InsDetail").is(":visible"))
     $(".stateDiv").val(1);
  else
    $(".stateDiv").val(0);
});

});
```

In this way you can control  the state also server-side

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach (hack) in ASP.NET Webforms is to persist dynamic client data in a `hidden` input field like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="persistedData" value="someValue" runat="server" />
```

Then you can use this information to set the style on the server properly and render the style correctly after postback.